# How to simulate DataTrigger with Avalonia?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, avaloniaui

I would like to change the cell content with an image based on its binding value.
This is how I did for a WPF application.

```xml
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Updated" Width="96" CanUserSort="True" SortMemberPath="Updated" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CenterAlignmentColumnHeaderStyle}">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Name="MyImage" Source="Assets/Loading.ico" MaxWidth="16" MaxHeight="16" Margin="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Updated, IsAsync=True}" Value="false">
                    <Setter TargetName="MyImage" Property="Source" Value="Assets/False.ico" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Updated, IsAsync=True}" Value="true">
                    <Setter TargetName="MyImage" Property="Source" Value="Assets/True.ico" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

But it seems Triggers doesn't exist in Avalonia.

```xml
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="Auto"
                        SortMemberPath="Updated">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="Updated"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                   HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                   Padding="20 0 0 0" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Padding="0"
                      IsChecked="{Binding Updated^}"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      IsEnabled="False" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Is there a way to simulate this?

Comment: Have you tried using DataTriggerBehavior from Avalonia.Xaml.Behaviors package?

Comment: Thanks, it works but it seems it [doesn't work with resource images](https://github.com/wieslawsoltes/AvaloniaBehaviors/issues/76) and it breaks the Rider previewer.

Comment: You can use this markup extension `    public class LoaderExtension : MarkupExtension
    {
        private readonly string _uri;

        public LoaderExtension(string uri)
        {
            _uri = uri;
        }
        
        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => 
            new BitmapTypeConverter().ConvertFrom((ITypeDescriptorContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITypeDescriptorContext)), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, _uri);
    }`

Usage: Value="{local:Loader /Assets/Image.png}"

Answer (score 1):

I managed to achieve something similar using Avalonia's [Binding Classes](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/data-binding/binding-classes) feature.

I've removed some of the noise from this example, but essentially this adds two classes, `IsUpdated` and `NotUpdated`, and applies different styles for each:

```
<Image Source="Assets/Loading.ico" Classes.IsUpdated={Binding Updated} Classes.NotUpdated={Binding !Updated}>
  <Image.Styles>
    <Style Selector="Image.IsUpdated">
       <Style.Setters>
         <Setter Property="Source" Value="Assets/True.ico"/>
       </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
    <Style Selector="Image.NotUpdated">
      <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Source" Value="Assets/False.ico"/>
      </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
  </Image.Styles>
</Image>
```